# A CW is of countable type, iff all its homotopy groups are countable? (References?)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cw-complexes, brown-representability

When constructing a classifying space $BPL$ for piecewise linear microbundles,
one would like it to be a polyhedron, i.e. a locally finite simplicial complex.
Milnor solved this by showing that the isomorphism classes of pl microbundles $mb_{PL}(S^n)$ over each sphere are countable. Then some special version of Browns representablility theorem yields a countable CW complex $BPL$ and simplicial approximation gives a countable simplicial complex version of this space.

Now, one can easily show that being (locally) countable, locally finite and locally compact is the same thing for a CW or simplicial complex up to homotopy equivalence. 
(Whitehead does something like this (including simplicial approximation) in his ["combinatorial homotopy"](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/jhcwch1.pdf) article. There is also a summary on the first page of Milnor's ["on spaces having the homotopy type of a CW complex"](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/milnorcw.pdf).
There he also says that this is that same as being homotopy equivalent to an absolute neighbourhood retract.)

Knowing this I was wondering about the statement in the title:

> Given a (connected) CW complex $X$ with countable homotopy groups,
>   the functor $[.,X]$ satisfies the conditions of Brown's theorem and moreover it takes countable values on the spheres. So there should, by a similar argument as above, be a countable CW complex $Y$ representing this functor and by the usual arguments (Yoneda, Whitehead) we can see that it is homotopy equivalent to $X$.

The converse holds as the homotopy groups of a finite CW complex are finitely generated and taking the limit over a countable index set preserves countablility.

Did I make some stupid mistakes in the argument above and if not:
Does anyone know a good reference for this "countable version" of Brown's theorem or even directly for this classification of CW complexes of "countable type" in terms of homotopy groups?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The claim in this question that the homotopy groups of a finite CW complex are finitely generated is incorrect. See (counter-)example 4.27 in [Hatcher](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is simply-connected, then the homotopy groups will be countable iff the homology groups are countable; and then one can build $X$ by a homology resolution using Moore spaces for countable groups, resulting in countably many cells.

Comment: Thank you a lot; do you any reference, where I can look up homology resolutions ? I think I got the idea, but I'd like to see how you do this formally. In addition I'd prefer not to require simply-connected, do you think it can be handled by taking the universal cover?

Comment: What if we take Eilenberg-Mac Lane-spaces instead of Moore spaces? Then, the analogue should be a Posnikov system and we wouldn't need the simply-connected. I can prove that $K(G,n)$ is of countable type for $G$ countable, but I do not know whether there are problems, because this is only the _homotopy_ fibre.

Comment: I think going to the universal cover works, so Jeff's arguement resolves your question also in the non-simply-connected case. Note however that the analogous statement for "countable" replaced by "finitely generated" is not true, see e.g. this paper: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2373106?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents paper

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't quite figure out the proof for non-simply connected spaces sketched in the comments to Jeff Strom's answer, so I'm posting a more detailed answer in which direction ($\Leftarrow$) of the claim is instead proved using CW approximation.

**Claim:**
 Cosider a topological space that is homotopy equivalent to a connected CW complex. The space is homotopy equivalent to a countable CW complex if and only if all its homotopy groups are countable.

*Proof*:
($\Rightarrow$)  Suppose $X$ is a homotopy equivalent to a connected countable CW complex.  We may as well assume that $X$ itself is a CW complex with these properties.  By Theorem C of [[Wall](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970382?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970382?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), or by a direct argument, $\pi_1(X)$ is countable.  It follows that the universal cover $\tilde X$ of $X$ with the canonical CW structure (see Proposition 2.3.9 in [[Fritsch & Piccinini]](https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/4493/1/4493.pdf)) is also countable.  Applying Theorem C of [[Wall](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970382?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970382?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) once again, we find that all homology groups of the simply connected CW complex $\tilde X$ are countable. As countable abelian groups form a Serre class within the category of all abelian groups, this implies that all homotopy groups of $\tilde X$ are also countable.  As the higher homotopy groups of $X$ agree with those of $\tilde X$, this shows that all homotopy groups of $X$ are countable, as claimed.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose conversely that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a connected CW complex with countable homotopy groups.  Then the usual construction of a CW approximation $X'\to X$ as in, say, § 10.5 of [[May](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf)](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf), yields a countable CW complex $X'$ which is, by Whitehead's Theorem, homotopy equivalent to $X$.  To see that $X'$ is countable, recall that  $X'$ is constructed inductively as a colimit of spaces $X_k$.  The cells of $X_1$ are indexed by elements of the homotopy groups $\pi_i(X)$, which are countable by assumption, so $X_1$ is countable. The additional cells added to obtain $X_{k+1}$ from $X_k$ are indexed by pairs of elements of the group $\pi_k(X_k)$.  Assuming by induction that $X_k$ is countable, we find from the previous part of the proof that $\pi_k(X_k)$ is countable, and hence that $X_{k+1}$ is countable. Thus, each subcomplex $X_k$ is countable, and hence so is $X'$. $\square$

[Wall: Finiteness Conditions for CW-Complexes](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970382?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)
  [Fritsch & Piccinini: Cellular Structures in Topology](https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/4493/1/4493.pdf)
  [May: A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf)